# How to implement unit tests in a database-backed ASP.NET application (also UI testing)

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

ASP.NET apps that I've developed (on ASP.NET 2.0) have typically been backed by a database; the great majority of the .NET code on the server loads data in the form of a `DataSet` or `SqlDataReader` and uses it to databind something like a `DataGrid`.  The meaningful logic is either database dependent or user interface dependent.

In this context, how should I implement unit tests that would be run by a continuous integration server (probably CruiseControl.NET)?  Should I set up a test database connection for it to use to test CRUD operations and more complex SPROCs, or should more logic be contained in the .NET code and not in a SPROC?  This becomes more complex when there is structure in the database that the application expects to find (such as a Users table in something I'm writing for a CMS).

Also, what are the best ways to do unit-testing of user interfaces?  I've found [NUnitASP](http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/), which is now abandoned but mentions [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MVP pattern (Model View Presenter). This should allow you to isolate the behaviour of your system and unit test it properly.

Also, consider switching to MVC (I would go with Fubu over ASP.NET MVC). This will allow you to test controllers and have a more rails-like experience.

To automate, I use WatiN (like watir but for .NET). On top of it I use StoryTeller (Google "StoryTeller Jeremy Miller") to present what is happening in a more human readable way and to provide templates for QA to use.

I would highly recommend against any business logic in sprocs. Stay away from them. Look at the repository pattern to abstract away getting and setting data.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: What if the business logic does a lot of data filtering?  .NET code is always going to be slower at queries than SQL.

Comment: Then you are looking at rhino etl. I wouldn't go with ssis as it's unmaintainable.